# Date looping in angularjs or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I want to input two dates in my textfield. The first date is `12/15/2014` (month/day/year) and the second date is `01/13/2015`. There are 31 days in December right? I enter 15 of December so the loop will start at 15 and end in 13 of January. 
Now I want to loop using the days of the month. My desired output would be:

```
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
```

My question: Is it possible to do what I want using loopings? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create 2 dates, one for the start date and one for the end date. The date object in Javascript has a setDays method, which you can use to loop through the dates.

```
var currentDate = new Date(2014, 11, 15);
var endDate = new Date(2015, 0, 13);
while(currentDate <= endDate) {
    currentDate = new Date(currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1));
    console.log(currentDate.getDate());
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxpjzk23/)

Comment: Thank you Ricconect. How could I see the output of the code? what variable should I console log?

Comment: @Sloopy i updated Ricconect answer. Have a look at it

Comment: @Sloopy You should use `currentDate.getDate()` to get the day of the month

Comment: @Hudixt I appriciate improving my answer but I think the fiddle you eddited in my answer was not workable, with first clicking away 30 alert boxes before you can see anything

Comment: I tried using console.log but it stuck my  computer so to show it i used alert

Comment: @Hudixt I had check the updated answer but my browser hangs. btw, thank you

Comment: @Ricconnect I have another question, Is it okay if you convert it to for loop? cuz I want to see only the days. :-) Please if you don't mind

Comment: @Sloopy fixed a bug in the way the month was set, month 0 is january :) I have added a jsfiddle to demonstrate it, and only the day of the month is printed to the console. What do you mean exactly by "I only want the days"?

Comment: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/178816)

Comment: I checked it and its working fine now :) . .  My browser doesn't hangs or stuck in my computer. . Thank you very much again.

Comment: hi @TravisJ . I get what you mean so sorry. . I just wanted to get the exact output that I want.  :)

Comment: @Sloopy if you see this answer as the answer to your question, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Lol okay. sorry. I forgot it. Thanks